# Start screensaver on still pictures

Tags: monitor, screensaver

I have an Ubuntu box connected to a plasma TV. Still images reduce the lifetime of plasma TVs and may cause pixel-burn. I am looking for a technique to start the screensaver if the picture on the monitor is still for a while but prevents the screensaver if the picture is moving. Here is my not-working piece of python code but any solution using python or otherwise is good for me:

```
import gtk.gdk
import time
from subprocess import *

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()

while (True):
    buf1 = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
    pb1 = buf1.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
    time.sleep(3)
    buf2 = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
    pb2 = buf2.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])

    pix1 = pb1.get_pixels()
    pix2 = pb2.get_pixels()
    diffs = 0
    for i in range(len(pix1)):
        if(pix1[i] != pix2[i]):
            diffs = diffs + 1
    if(diffs > 10000):
        call(["xset", "dpms", "force", "on"])
        call(["gnome-screensaver-command", "--exit"])
```

Comment: Do you really want that? I have less than 10000 diffs while I'm typing this comment. With PC use, (near) still images are unfortunately very much normal (every time you read something or write something for that matter). At the same time a single animation (such as a on screen clock) could prevent it ever from coming up.

Comment: The threshold and the timeout are adjustable. The purpose of the script is to prevent screensaver when e.g., a movie is being played but the keyboard is not being touched.

Comment: For the screensaver during movie problem I found a different solution in `xautolock`. You can set it up to prevent locking when the mouse pointer is e.g. exactly in the lower left corner of the screen. So when I watch a movie, I just move the mouse there, and it doesn't lock.

Comment: If you want to stick with your script, you should optimize your loop to only take one screenshot per iteration, instead of two. Also check if Python doesn't have an image library capable of returning the number of diffs, the for loop is just unbearably slow. Way too much overhead for a background screensaver control.

Comment: Of course it can be optimized. But overhead is not the main issue of my script right now since it runs only once every few minutes. The main issue is that it doesn't work. Why? I don't know.